# set file as latest file

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm downloading the file every 30 minutes. I compare this file to a manual file that I was created (for first time downloaded and manual file are same). If downloaded file have some difference then these file should be set as latest file. After 30 minutes new file will downloaded. Then these file should compare with latest file. And so on.

I found these much code for file download & save :

```
wget -O /path/to/file/b.txt https://www.xyz.com/list/?exit

comm -1 -3 <(sort a.txt) <(sort b.txt)
```

where a.txt is manual file and b.txt is downloaded file.

please help me out.

Comment: Get into the habit of quoting URLs so that the shell doesn't try to process special characters (`&`, `?`, etc.), i.e. `wget -O /path/to/file/b.txt 'https://www.contoso.com/list/?exit'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `cmp` utility inside an `if-statement`

```
if cmp -s a.txt b.txt; then
  echo a.txt is same as b.txt
  ##: Do something here.
else
  echo files did not match
  mv -v b.txt a.txt  ##: Make b.txt as the latest file by renaming to a.txt
fi
```

The `echo` is there just to send a message to `stdout`.

Assuming a.txt is the name of the latest file that mv b.txt to a.txt is what you want otherwise give it a name of the latest file.

I will leave the `downloading every 30 minutes` part to you, or maybe someone can chime in and help you with that.

Comment: It works perfectly for comparing two files. thanks

Comment: You don't want to sort either of these files, otherwise you'll miss differences in the files caused only by ordering. A simple `cmp -s a.txt b.txt` is perfectly sufficient here.

Comment: Yes, that is also true, thanks for pointing that out, I guess it is up to the op what he wants to do now.

Comment: @roaima yes, thank you.

Comment: Updated the answer and remove the sorting of files.

Comment: I get the output "Files did not match". Now I want to set b.txt (previous downloaded file) file as latest file. so next time I can compare b.txt file with new downloaded file. Any one help?

Comment: @Jetchisel  I already done this. I used 'mv b.txt a.txt'. btw thanks for helping me.